# Redirect entire site with htaccess to other domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect entire site from one domain to other.
I works when i declare 
RewriteRule with R=301 but user can easy notice that
he is redirected to other url in his navi bar.
The result i want to achieve is using remote server to display content
with url keeped from local server.

For example:
User types example1.com, the htaccess gets content from example2.com
(for main page and every subpage in example1.com). Server does not
redirect his browser but just loads remote data from example1.com.

It works when i just use file_get_contentes('example2.com... but
problem comes if there is some $_POST data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer  to your question, but this solution is not optimal for a number of reasons:

1. It depends on *two* servers being up.
2. It is slower as the  request has to be made twice.
3. It takes up double the bandwidth, and if you use a PHP script, additional resources on the proxying server.

Are you sure  you *have* to do this?

If you really do, look into Apache's [proxying capabilities](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead of a PHP script that can deal with the problem you describe (and several others, for example session management, and passing through the `HTTP_REFERER` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` variables). [Here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) is a tutorial for it.

Note that this requires root access to the server.

Answer (score 3):

The clean solution is to have the server that handles `example2.com` respond to requests sent to `example1.com`. This is usually done by configuring an Apache virtual host to use `ServerName example2.com` and `ServerAlias example1.com`.

If you cannot afford to do this, you should rely on an actual proxy-and-reverse-proxy instead of doing it yourself with PHP: it's faster, and it handles absolute URLs correctly (what happens if `example2.com` returns HTML that contains an `<a href="http://example2.com/xxx">` ?). Apache has a correct proxy and reverse proxy implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible with .htaccess.
Could you not add example1.com as an alias in the httpd.conf for example2.com and change the DNS records for example1.com to point to the same machine as example2.com ?

That'll achieve what you are after and cuts out the middleman (example1.com's server).

Comment: I cant do that cause the domain is pointing to email server at example1, or maybe there is a way to point example2 to http at example1 but email server at example2?

Comment: you mean email for anything@example1.com still needs to go to the example1.com server? that's fine you can keep the MX record still pointing at the example1.com server for email to still go there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do such a redirect across domains using only mod_rewrite. A rewriterule that writes to an address on another server will always behave as if it has an R flag.

You'll probably have to use some server-side scripting, not sure how though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => (isset($_POST)) ? http_build_query($_POST) : '',
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result  = file_get_contents('http://example2.com/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false, $context);
```

I realise that is quite lame solution but it works well.